# Radiobutton value show in datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, radio-button

when I click any cell data load from access db how I can get radiobutton values from access db

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
 textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
 comboBox1 .Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
 dateTimePicker1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
```

its works
 example I want show gender from database to radiobutton

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that : In a datagridview data values are always stored as System.Object..When you need to use this data properly you need to cast to boxed data format..

For the reason of this, you convert the cell data to string with .ToString() method..

So, when you need a radiobutton value (its a boolean - either 1-0, or true-false) you need to convert the value to boolean :

```
YourRadioButton.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(YourDataGridview.CurrentRow.Cells[YourBooleanCellID].Value);
```